# setState is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase

I'm trying to add a delete button to the table so I can get `el.id` and delete it. I can't read `el.id`, so I wanted to add it to states.

Please tell me if there is another solution or if it can be fixed.

This is my code:

```
componentDidMount: function(){
       var url = 'I have an api here'

       axios.get(url).then(function(response){
         var arr = $.map(response.data, function(el) {
           $.each(el, function (i, word) {
             this.setState({el: el});
               $("#data").append(
                 '<tr><td>' + el.name + '</td><td>' + el.email + '</td><td>' + el.category + '</td><td>' + el.address + '</td><td>' + '<button onClick={console.log(el)} class="btn btn-primary">delete</button>'
               );
           });
         });
         $('body').addClass('stop-scrolling');
       })
  },
```

Comment: Is the context of `this` correctly assigned?

Comment: Switch to using arrow functions so `this` is bound to your React component. Also, using jQuery for DOM manipulation while using React is a code smell / anti-pattern.

Comment: you have to bind this to the class scope : Here is a good article : https://medium.com/@housecor/react-binding-patterns-5-approaches-for-handling-this-92c651b5af56#.8g18iql2s

Answer (score -1):

you're calling `this.setState` inside a callback function so `this` doesn't to the expected context.

you can store the value of `this` inside a variable :

```
componentDidMount: function(){
   var url = 'I have an api here';
   var self = this;

   axios.get(url).then(function(response){
     var arr = $.map(response.data, function(el) {
       $.each(el, function (i, word) {
         self.setState({el: el});
         $("#data").append('<tr><td>' + el.name + '</td><td>' + el.email + '</td><td>' + el.category + '</td><td>' + el.address + '</td><td>' + '<button onClick={console.log(el)} class="btn btn-primary">delete</button>');
       });
     });
     $('body').addClass('stop-scrolling');
   })
},
```

or you can use arrow function to solve your problem

Comment: there are better ways to bind this. for example: https://medium.com/@housecor/react-binding-patterns-5-approaches-for-handling-this-92c651b5af56#.8g18iql2s

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'el' of undefined
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (VM23973 suppliers?_k=2dp4j7:1)
onclick @ VM23973 suppliers?_k=2dp4j7:1

Comment: this is another problem, what is the value of `response.data` ?